# Garbage value written in .csv file by ADC

Tags: usb, adc

I'm using the PIC24 microcontroller and I'm using a Thumb drive to save information from the microcontroller USB transmitter and receiver pins. The data is saved in the Thumbdrive using the '.CSV' file format. The following is the data collected:

```
3/19/2018    12:10  35      
3/19/2018    12:10  7   
3/19/2018    12:10  7   
3/19/2018    12:10  7       
3/19/2018    12:10  19      
3/19/2018    12:10  30      
3/19/2018    12:10  37      
3/19/2018    12:10  44  
3/19/2018    12:10  45      
3/19/2018    12:10  48      
3/19/2018    12:10  58      
3/19/2018    12:10  67      
3/19/2018    12:10  69      
3/19/2018    12:10  79      
3/19/2018    12:10  90      
3/19/2018    12:10  96      
3/19/2018    12:10  99  
3/19/2018    12:10  110     
3/19/2018    12:10  USBSÅV43/19/2018     12:10  126
3/19/2018    12:10  130     
3/19/2018    12:10  140     
3/19/2018    12:10  152     
3/19/2018    12:10  155     
3/19/2018    12:10  159     
3/19/2018    12:10  168     
3/19/2018    12:10  182     
3/19/2018    12:10  184     
3/19/2018    12:10  193 
3/19/2018    12:10  208     
3/19/2018    12:10  218     
3/19/2018    12:10  222     
3/19/2018    12:10  230     
3/19/2018    12:10  245     
3/19/2018    12:10  256     
3/19/2018    12:10  256     
253/19/2018  12:10  256     
3/19/2018    12:10  256
```

As you can see, the first column is for the date(mm/dd/yyyy), the second column is for the time(hh:mm) and 3rd column is for the digital value. In one of the rows, I got a ADC value starting with 'USBS'. Then in the second last row, the month in the 1st column was noted as 253 instead of just 3. Why am I getting  garbage values and how can I get rid of it?

The following is the line of code that allows me to write the data on the thumb drive:

```
charCount = sprintf(printBuffer, "%d/%d/20%d, %d:0%d,  %d, %d\r\n" , month, date, year, hour, minute, ADC);
```

Comment: No, that's the line that assembles the results *for* writing onto the drive. The actual code for writing is much larger. And it has a bug.

Comment: the reason that you are getting the "USBS" is because your program has written it .... since you did not include the program code, it is impossible to guess which part of the program has caused the faulty data to be written

Comment: Yes, I'm just trying to assemble the the data from the code, but I was just wondering why random data is added to the .csv file. The striking part is that it occurs irregularly.

Comment: don't be asking us until you provide the program listing .... -1

Comment: could be software, maybe a race condition or some non-reentrant code somewhere... could be hardware, badly placed or insufficient bypass capacitors... unanswerable without more information.

Comment: @user180997 because your program is adding random data to the .csv file.

Comment: Aside from the fact that the “CSV” that you posted contains no Cs (and doesn’t match the code that you provided, as pointed out by others already), and ignoring the fact that your code contains more specifiers than arguments, the minutes field will not produce the results you’re after. (Phew, I almost got lost in that run-on sentence.) If minutes is 12, for example, your code will write “012”. You want “%02d” instead.

Answer (score 1):

One really obvious bug is that your format string specifies 7 data fields, but you're only supplying 6 additional arguments. `sprintf()` (and friends) will happily read whatever garbage is on the stack and put it into any unspecified fields.

Also, note that you aren't showing us the contents of the actual CSV file; you're showing us the result of passing the file through some other program, which is applying its own interpretation to what it's finding there.